# find the position of a point inside a triangle to have specific area for each part (2D)

Tags: matlab, math, optimization, system, equations

Consider an in-plane Triangle (Black) with 3 edge points, (1,2,3). 
The area of this triangle is considered to be A. Then for an arbitrary point inside the triangle and connecting this point to each edges, we will have 3 small triangles, (Areas A12 , A23, A13). 
If I know the area ratios between the big and small triangles as :

- n1 = A12 / A
- n2 = A23 / A
- n3 = A13 / A

I want to find the position of the arbitrary point (x0,y0).

---

*note : given three edges of a triangle, the area can be calculated as:
(x1,y1) , (x2,y2) , (x3,y3)

A = 0.5 * det([x1 y1 1 ; x2 y2 1 ; x3 y3 1]);

Comment: Are you sure this is a well posed problem? It seems to me you have too many unknowns and too few constraints: Suppose you fix one point of A to the origin (i.e., (x1,y1)=(0,0)). You also fix the first edge to lie on the x axis (i.e., y2 = 0 ). You still have 5 unknowns: x2,x3,y3,x0 and y0. However, you have only 3 equations with n1, n2 and n3? Am I missing something here?

Comment: It is not really clear, but i guess that the coordinates of the corners of the outer triangle are known? Perhaps you could add a sketch of the situation and indicate which things are known and what needs to be solved?

Comment: I had a sketch but I couldn't upload it because of my reputation score ;), by the way the inputs are: (x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3,n1,n2,n3) and the output is: x0,y0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be simply solved with the barycentric coordinates. Given a point p and the triangle points t1, t2, t3, the point p can be expressed as

```
p = s1 * t1 + s2 * t2 + s3 * t3
```

where s1-s3 are the barycentric coordinates. Those can be interpreted as the relative area of the triangle opposite to the triangle point. And this is exactly what you are given with n1-n3.

So you can calculate your arbitrary point with the above formula.

Comment: I checked the concept of barycentric coordinates: starting from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycentric_coordinate_system_(mathematics) . Thank you